# How to give apps access to existing Secure Storage

Tags: security, backup, lineageos

How can I grant the apps on an upgraded Android, to the existing Secure Storage data?

To prepare for upgrading from LineageOS 14.1 to LineageOS 15.1, I made sure to wipe only Cache, System, and Data partitions. Specifically, I did *not* select Internal Storage to wipe, because I want the apps to continue to have access to the existing data.

Then, I followed the [instructions to install LineageOS 15.1](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/bullhead/install), which succeeded.

Now when I re-install the apps, such as Password Store and DAVDroid, they do not seem to have the same data from internal storage (they act as though there is no data yet). How do I get these apps to use the data, specific to each app, in Internal Storage that was not wiped?

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress on your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the consensus I found when searching for answers, it seems **there is no way to do this**.